# PHP Count Unique Visitors ,, Not Works

Tags: php, cookies

I am willing to count unique visitors once landing on a specific page,
I wrote the below code, but the database updates each visit not uniquely,
tried to check the cookie in chrome settings, but did not find **TestCookie** 
Then tried to check from Inspect->Network->Cookies I found my cookie in **response cookies**, 
Actually, I don't know if this means that it was saved or not, because if it is saved, so why database updates each repeated visit...

```
<?php include "db.php"; ?>
    <?php
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['TestCookie'])){
      setcookie("TestCookie","yes",60*60*24*320);
      mysqli_query($dbConnection,"UPDATE visits SET otal_count = total_count+1");
      print_r($_COOKIE);
    
    }else{
      return false;
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to change third (expires_or_options) paramater of setcookie to

```
time() + 60*60*24*320

setcookie("TestCookie","yes",time() + 60*60*24*320);
```

Comment: wow, thank you, the expiry date for the cookie was 0 , now it's working fine, thank you :)